# Reading a shapefile into networkx as undirected graph

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, graph, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import approximation as ax

Road = nx.read_shp('/Users/benjaminhendel/Downloads/scatteredroads.shp') #Reading Road Data 
Base = nx.read_shp('/Users/benjaminhendel/Downloads/testptssnapped.shp') #Reading Terminal Node
nodes = list(Base.nodes) #Creating list of terminal nodes
Road = Road.to_undirected()
st_tree = ax.steinertree.steiner_tree(Road,nodes,weight='length')
```

I'm trying to read a shapefile into networkx and run `steiner_tree` approximation on it. It tells me that my graph is directed. When I make it undirected, it gives me the error:

```
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: G is not a connected graph. metric_closure is not defined.
```

Comment: Not relevant, but should be Base.nodes() ?

Comment: In QGIS I've run v.clean and dissolve to make sure that the paths on my .shp layer are connected. Is there perhaps some level of pre-processing step needed to make sure you have a 'connected graph'?

Answer (score 3):

[A graph is said to be connected if there is a path between every pair of vertex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/graph_theory_connectivity.htm).

Therefore create a new full connected Graph with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
 import itertools
 Road = nx.read_shp('stac_graph.shp')
 # control
 Road2 = Road.to_undirected()
 nx.is_connected(Road2)
 False
 # new graph with path between every pair of vertex
 G = nx.Graph()
 # add original nodes
 G.add_nodes_from(Road)
 # create edges
 G.add_edges_from(itertools.combinations(Road, 2))
 # control
 nx.is_connected(G)
 True
 # and
 nodes = list(G.nodes) 
 nx.steinertree.steiner_tree(G,nodes,weight='length')
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0xa27c5da58>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is G-ex? it is never defined. And where do I input my nodes shapefile?

Comment: And doesn't this create an edge between every node? This isn't what my original road network file is like

Comment: a mistake, corrected, thanks

Comment: Doesn't work, it connects every vertex, I wanted it to run on a second shapefile of nodes